# Stop MediaElement from other window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the Main Window, lets call it 'A' and a second Window, 'B'.
I have a MediaElement in Window B, and I need to make it stop playing when I press a button in Window A.

(The Window B, is actually a UserControl)

So, this is what I have been trying:

Window B:

```
<MediaElement Name="mediaElement" LoadedBehavior="Manual" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
```

---

```
public void stopVideo()
{
mediaElement.Stop();
}
```

Window A:

```
WindowB newWindowB = new WindowB();
newWindowB.stopVideo();
```

However, whenever I press the button with the code in the Window A, the video won't stop.

Comment: What/where is the problem?

Comment: It doesn't work. I press the button in the Window A and the video doesn't stop.

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with creating a *new* object before calling it?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I'm sorry, I don't quite understand. The media element is created and running inside the user control. But when I try to stop it from the main Window it does nothing.

Comment: Look at your code. You make a **new** WindowB and call `stopVideo` on it. Why would that affect the existing instance of WindowB (with the video on it)?

Comment: @BradleyDotNETOhh, that makes sense. Then, how should I call it? When I reference just to de WindowB, it wont show me the option "stioVideo", instead of it it shows me "StopVideoCallback".